# Stencil mask with AlphaTestEffect

Tags: xna-4.0, stencil

I am trying to pull off the following effect in XNA 4.0:

[image]

The purple area has 50% opacity. I have gotten pretty close with the following code:

```
public static DepthStencilState AlwaysStencilState = new DepthStencilState()
        {

            StencilEnable = true,
            StencilFunction = CompareFunction.Always,
            StencilPass = StencilOperation.Replace,
            ReferenceStencil = 1,
            DepthBufferEnable = false,
        };

public static DepthStencilState EqualStencilState = new DepthStencilState()
        {
            StencilEnable = true,
            StencilFunction = CompareFunction.Equal,
            StencilPass = StencilOperation.Keep,
            ReferenceStencil = 1,
            DepthBufferEnable = false,
        };

...

if (_alphaEffect == null)
{
       _alphaEffect = new AlphaTestEffect(_spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice);
       _alphaEffect.AlphaFunction = CompareFunction.LessEqual;
       _alphaEffect.ReferenceAlpha = 129;
       Matrix projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, _spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth, _spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight, 0, 0, 1); 
       _alphaEffect.Projection = world.SystemManager.GetSystem<RenderSystem>().Camera.View * projection;
}

_mask = new RenderTarget2D(_spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice, _spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth, _spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8);
_spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(_mask);
_spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target | ClearOptions.Stencil, Color.Transparent, 0, 0); 

_spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, AlwaysStencilState, null, _alphaEffect);
_spriteBatch.Draw(sprite.Texture, position, sprite.SourceRectangle,Color.White, 0f, sprite.Origin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
_spriteBatch.End();

_spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, EqualStencilState, null, null);
_spriteBatch.Draw(_maskTex, new Vector2(x * _maskTex.Width, y * _maskTex.Height), null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
_spriteBatch.End();

_spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
_spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

_spriteBatch.Begin();
_spriteBatch.Draw((Texture2D)_mask, Vector2.Zero, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, layer/max_layer);
_spriteBatch.End();
```

My problem is, I can't get the AlphaTestEffect to behave. I can either mask over the semi-transparent purple junk and fill it in with the green design, or I can draw over the completely opaque grassy texture. How can I specify the exact opacity that needs to be replace with the green design?

Comment: Hi Brendan, and welcome to GDSE. You don't need to sign your posts since they're already signed with your user information, and you don't need to dump a tag in your title since your question already has tags. I've edited both out.

Comment: Why can't you replace the purple with a proper alpha channel and just draw it last?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do this with the AlphaTestEffect(in fact I does not know how ATE works). I recently want to draw some kind of menu, that fills the the the stencil buffer correctly and is a kind of mask.

My PixelShader looks like this:

```
float4 PSFunc (VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
    float4 texel = tex2D(TextureSampler, input.TexCoord);
    clip(texel.w - AlphaClipValue);
    return texel;
}
```

AlphaClipValue defines what pixel are visible in texture. e.g. 0.8f defines that alle Alpha values in the texture that are above 204 gets drawn. Other pixel get cliped.

```
protected readonly DepthStencilState DrawMaskDepthStencilState = 
    new DepthStencilState(){
        StencilEnable = true,
        StencilFunction = CompareFunction.Always,
        StencilPass = StencilOperation.Invert,
        ReferenceStencil = 0,
        DepthBufferEnable = true,
    };
protected readonly DepthStencilState DrawSceneDepthStencilState = 
    new DepthStencilState(){
    StencilEnable = true,
        StencilFunction = CompareFunction.Equal,
        StencilPass = StencilOperation.Keep,
        ReferenceStencil = 0,
        DepthBufferEnable = true,
    };
```

Now the Draw()

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime){
    //set state that is able to draw
    GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DrawMaskDepthStencilState;

    //set texture and AlphaClipValue (1 means only pixel with Alpha==255 gets drawn)
    DrawMenuEffect.Texture = _maskTexture;
    DrawMenuEffect.AlphaClipValue = 1f;
    DrawMenuEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
    GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip,    FullScreenQuadStripVertices,0,2);

    GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DrawSceneDepthStencilState;

    // Now draw rest of the scene 
}
```

I using my own projected quads to draw the texture, because I do not like the SpriteBatch(it resets some state that is does not reset). But I think it should work with SpriteBatch, too. Otherwise you can look [here](http://projectvanquish.wordpress.com/tag/fullscreen-quad/) to see how to create them.